# Difference between code cleanup in finally block and after catch block (C#)

Tags: asp.net, try-catch, code-cleanup

What is the difference between adding cleanup code in finally block and cleanup code after the catch block ?

```
     try
     {
      //some code
     }
     catch
     {
     }
     finally
     {
      //cleanup
     }
```

and

```
     try
     {
      //some code
     }
     catch
     {
     }
      //cleanup
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you throw a throwable from the `try .. catch` block that is not caught by this `catch`, the cleanup code inside the `finally` clause will execute and the code immediately after the `catch` block will not.

Answer (score 0):

In your second case if the code rethrows an exception or return from the catch block then your `cleanup` code will not be called. In case of `finally` block it will be executed even if you have an exception or a return statement from  the catch block.

The [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zwc8s4fz(v=vs.110).aspx) says:

> By using a finally block, you can clean up any resources that are
>   allocated in a try block, and you can run code even if an exception
>   occurs in the try block. Typically, the statements of a finally block
>   run when control leaves a try statement. The transfer of control can
>   occur as a result of normal execution, of execution of a break,
>   continue, goto, or return statement, or of propagation of an exception
>   out of the try statement.